# Можно ли одновременно использовать Parallel Deployment и нативные сессии Shiro?

Tags: java, сессия, tomcat

В проекте использую Apache Tomcat 8.0.28 и Apache Shiro 1.3.2. В Tomcat'е использую фичу [Parallel deployment](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) для деплоя нескольких версий одного приложения.

Новые требования к проекту привели к необходимости использования [нативных сессий](http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-NativeSessions) Shiro. Но после включения нативных сессий оказалось, что Parallel Deployment больше не функционирует, т. к. Tomcat теперь ничего не знает про сессии, а для работы Parallel Deployment нужны сессии.

Есть ли способ использовать одновременно Parallel Deployment в Tomcat'е и нативные сессии Shiro. Или, может, есть альтернативы для Parallel Deployment?